# How can I prevent bogus one-letter empty contacts from appearing in a dual sim phone?

Tags: dual-sim

I have a dual SIM phone and my address books keeps getting populated by these empty bogus one-letter contacts that are shown as being read from the second SIM, see picture:[[image: bogus_contacts]]
If I delete them, after some time, they appear again. I had some saved contacts (like 112 aka European 911) from my primary SIM that also appeared in this fashion but after I deleted them from the first SIM, they stopped appearing. However, I cannot deleted those from the second SIM card, because they are not there! I have this confirmed by another user of hte same phone (Gemini PDA) and also by someone who used to own a dual SIM Sony Experia, so it seems like a bug in Android. Any idea what to do about it?

Comment: Easiest way might be going to the app's settings and tell it not to show SIM contacts at all.

Comment: That seems to work, it was well hidden in the app settings, and it also works for DW contacts that I actually use!

Comment: Cool! \o/ Could you please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then with a short step-by-step guide of what you did? Would help others in a similar situation, especially with that setting so well buried. Thanks in advance!